# TableLayoutPanel Last Row Size Too Big

Tags: c#, height, row, tablelayoutpanel

My application uses a TableLayoutPanel that resides within a TabPage.

If the number of items I add is relatively small (i.e. it doesn't "fill up" the whole tab page) then the last row's height is stretched. Here is a screenshot of what's happening:

[image: Table Layout Panel Last Row]

I have tried to change the properties of the table to Autosize, GrowAndShrink, etc. but nothing seems to stop this from happening.

Here are my current settings for the layout properties of the table:

[image: Table Layout Panel Layout Properties]

How can I get the last row to be the same size as the other rows?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to make some changes in your design, set dock property of TableLayoutPanel to top instead of fill.

Comment: Dock is set to None currently.

Comment: Well, make it top, I think this will help you.

Comment: I just made it top and set autosize to true and it worked thanks!

Comment: Answer my question and I will give you credit. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your design and your requirements I suggest you to make `Dock` property of `TableLayoutPanel` to top.

Answer (score 6):

I just had very similar problem. Filling `TableLayoutPanel` programatically (with autoscroll) and the last row was too high. Dock work-around was not suitable for me.

Fixed by adding empty `Label` as the last row. It "occupies" the last row, but is not visible. Enough for me.

Comment: Still makes the bottom of the table huge though. Lot of scrolling going on down there.

Answer (score 5):

Using the dock property solves the last row height problem, but creates another by changing the table width to match the container width (100%). I wanted the height in the last row to be correct but I do not want the forced 100% width.

Instead of using the Dock property, I used:

```
AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
```

That made the autosize work correctly on the last row and column.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where the last row was always too high in a TLP with more rows than could fit, using AutoScroll.

The solution was to turn AutoScroll off, set the row sizes from the TLP Rows collection, then turn AutoScroll back on again.

Answer (score 0):

1 pixel is the minimum unit! 
eg: 10 rows to average container height , if TableLayoutPanel height is 200, it's  perfect!
But if the TableLayoutPanel height is 199 . the computer unable to spilt one pixel;
so, the every row's height  must be 19 while the last row height is 19+（199 - 19*10）= 28；
 As a result: the last row is 10 heighter than other row.
What we need to do is avoid set the TableLayoutPanel height unabe to average.or we need to change the TableLayputPanel height !